# Android - Expected Resource of type ID

Tags: java, android, arcgis, esri

I have this code

```
final static int TITLE_ID = 1;
final static int REVIEW_ID = 2;
```

Now, I want to create a new layout in my main class

```
public View createContent() {
    // create linear layout for the entire view
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // create TextView for the title
    TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
    titleView.setId(TITLE_ID);
    titleView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    layout.addView(titleView);

    StarView sv = new StarView(this);
    sv.setId(REVIEW_ID);
    layout.addView(sv);

    return layout;
}
```

But when ever I call TITLE_ID and REVIEW_ID, it gives me an error

> Supplying the wrong type of resource identifier.
>   For example, when calling Resources.getString(int id), you should be passing R.string.something, not R.drawable.something.
>   Passing the wrong constant to a method which expects one of a specific set of constants. For example, when calling View#setLayoutDirection, the parameter must be android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR or android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL.

I don't have any problem running this code. I'm just wondering why it gives me an error. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict. Set TITLE_ID  and REVIEW_ID to very big numbers and try again.

Comment: you can manage using setTag() instead of SetId

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This is not a compiler error. It is just editor validation error(lint warning) as this is not a common way to deal with Ids.

So if your app supporting API 17 and higher,

you can call [View.generateViewId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()) as

```
  titleView.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

and

```
  sv.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

and for **API<17**

1. open your project's `res/values/` folder
2. create an xml file called `ids.xml`

with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="titleId" type="id" />
    <item name="svId" type="id" />
</resources>
```

then in your code,

```
  titleView.setId(R.id.titleId);
```

and

```
  sv.setId(R.id.svId);
```

---

And to disable this warning  (If you want)

In Android Studio click on light bulb on line with this 'error'. And select **Disable inspection** in first submenu.

Comment: When using generateViewId: What if I want to reference later a specific view? How would I know the id? Let's say the 10th out of 50 generated views?

Comment: The light bulb->inspection 'Constant and Resource Type Mismatches options'->Disable inspection trick was just what I needed!

Comment: Disabling inspection is bad practice. There are much better ways to disable the lint check on an instance without crippling lint altogether.

Answer (score 25):

You can also disable lint at build.gradle file.
Add these lines in your build.gradle file.

```
android { 
       lintOptions{
             disable "ResourceType"
       }
}
```

Comment: @Erwinus it will remove the lint flag for any issue related to ResourceType. It works to take away yellow marks, but is bad practice in coding. I have posted an alternative for only removing the lint flag for the specific instance.

Answer (score 9):

I am including this as an alternative to "fixing" the issue for those that cannot generate a view ID (ie. defining the ID before the view is actually present) and know what they are doing.

Directly above a variable declaration or method that contains the issue, simply include `@SuppressWarnings("ISSUE_IDENTIFIER")` to disable the lint warning for that instance.

In this case, it would be `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")`

Using general methods to disable the warning type is **bad practice** and can lead to unforeseen issues, such as memory leaks and unstable code. Don't publish garbage.

Make sure to undo the option to `Disable inspection` and remove these lines from the build.gradle:

```
android {
    lintOptions{
        disable "ResourceType"
    }
}
```