# CustomLoading in android ( error : expected resource of type drawable )

Tags: android

Can somebody recommend the best way to CustomLoading in android Project.

i using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997745/4667351).

my code :

```
_readNewsAsyncTaskManager = new ReadNewsAsyncTaskManager();

_loadigIcon.setImageResource(R.anim.loading_animation);// Error*
loadingViewAnim = (AnimationDrawable) _loadigIcon.getBackground();

// This line is to start Asyn Task only when OnCreate Method get completed, So Loading Icon Rotation Animation work properly
_loadigIcon.post(new Starter());
```

Error* : expected resource of type drawable

loading_animation :

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_6" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_7" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_8" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_9" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_10" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_11" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_12" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_13" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_14" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_15" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_16" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_17" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_18" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_19" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution :

Forget this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900747/custom-progress-dialog-with-squre-image-rotation-with-asyntask/19997745#19997745)

move loading_animation  file from anim folder to drawable folder

and loading_animation  file :

```
<animation-list
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
        <item android:duration="50">
            <clip
                android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_1"
                 />
        </item>
        <item android:duration="50">
            <clip
                android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_2"
                 />
        </item>
        <item android:duration="50">
            <clip
                android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_3"
                 />
        </item>
        <item android:duration="50">
            <clip
                android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_4"
                 />
        </item>
        <item android:duration="50">
            <clip
                android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
                android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loading_5"
                 />
        </item>
    </animation-list>
```

and i using this :

```
               <ProgressBar
                   android:layout_width="32sp"
                   android:layout_height="32sp"
                   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                   android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                   android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading_animation"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

This is not a compiler error. It is just editor validation error(lint warning) as this is not a common way to deal with Drawable.

There has 2 solutions：

1. Move the loading_animation file from anim folder to drawable folder
2. Replace
   `_loadigIcon.setImageResource(R.anim.loading_animation);`
   with

   `_loadigIcon.setImageResource(+R.anim.loading_animation);`

Reference the answer：[Android - Expected Resource of type ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696879/android-expected-resource-of-type-id)

Comment: see example code In [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html). animation.xml file must be in **res/drawable/** folder NOT res/anim/. and set background resource using  **R.drawable.animation** NOT R.anim.animation. I don't know history but i think need to adapt this solution.

Comment: What does mean plus sign? @shusheng007