# Android : How to create a customizable time table like structure with scrolling

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-tablelayout, timetable

In my application, I have to show a timetable as below.
[image]

Where subject can be changed by clicking on the 3 dot menu and which should be updated immediately.Also, both horizontal and vertical scrolling must be possible, when user scrolls horizontally then the Y-axis header should be frozen and when scrolls vertically then X-axis header should be frozen.How to create this in android?

Comment: This is a good place to start https://stackoverflow.com/a/7120175/493321

Comment: Recycler View with GridLayoutManager will help you out. https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/

Comment: @Stallion But how to create a syncronizable scrollable X &Y Header when using Recycler view ??

Comment: @basilisk I need a 3 dot facility in each data cell  like in the image

Comment: First you check out how to use RecyclerView with a sample. Now the three dots and actions are all customisable according to your requirement. What do you mean by synchronizable scrollable? The lock of X and Y correspondingly is something I am not sure about.

Comment: @Stallion I know to use recycler view, but i didn't know how to use a X and Y header which match with the recycler view scrolling.If there is no header i can easily use a recyclerview.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Recyclerview` in `HorizontalScrollview`

It will work perfectly..

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: How to associate a header on both x & y side ??

Comment: Just create a header.xml which contains header layout for recycler view and inflate it in recyclerView adapter. Now in your recyclerViewData layout create a layout in a complete row manner (including y header) with fix width of elements.

Comment: can u explain it with codes for both x and y header??

Comment: https://takeoffandroid.com/header-and-footer-layout-for-recylerview-3dd360134c1e

You can refer this link to inflate Header with recyclerview